# My problem is $U_x+\frac{Uy}{U} = U^2,\;\; U(x,1) = 1$. Please Help!

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Thank you for your attention.

My problem is

$U_x+\frac{Uy}{U} = U^2,\;\; U(x,1) = 1$.

I will really appreciate any clue in solving problems like this.

Am I right with :
$\frac{dx}{1}$ = $udy$ = $\frac{du}{u^2}$

if yes, then I am confused with how to solve these three curves intersection.

Comment: This is a quasi-linear first-order PDE, which can be solved by the method of characteristics.

Comment: Thank you. I actually have problem with wring the curves because of U in the denominator.

Comment: @Shay then try to solve $UU_x + U_y = U^3$.

Answer (score 2):

$$u_x+\frac{u_y}{u} = u^2$$

$\frac{dx}{1}=udy=\frac{du}{u^2}\quad$ is OK.

First characteristic equation, from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{u^2}$ :
$$\frac{1}{u}+x=c_1$$

Second characteristic equation, from $udy=\frac{du}{u^2}$ :
$$\frac{1}{2u^2}+y=c_2$$

General solution :
$$\frac{1}{2u^2}+y=F\left(\frac{1}{u}+x\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to boundary condition.

Boundary condition : $\quad u(x,1)=1$ .

This is a special case because the boundary condition is defined on a characteristic curve : $\quad \frac{1}{2u^2}+y=\frac{1}{2}+1=\frac{3}{2}=c_2$ .

$\frac{1}{u}+x=1+x$ and the solution $\frac{1}{2u^2}+y=F\left(\frac{1}{u}+x\right)$ is only possible if the function $F$ is a constant function : $\frac{1}{2u^2}+y=\frac32$

Finally, the solution is not function of $x$ :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-2y}}$$
To check, put it into the PDE.